# Ĉu naciaj asocianoj estas aŭtomate UEA-anoj?

Tags: movado

Lastatempe mi aniĝis ĉe la nacia Esperanto Asocio de mia denaska lando, la Esperanto Asocio de Britio.

Samtempe, mi ekvidis ĉe la informo pri la 102-a Universala Kongreso, ke ekzistis rabatoj por anoj de la Universala Esperanta Asocio.

Evidente, la naciaj Esperanto asocioj estas iel alligitaj al la UEA, sed **ĉu individuaj anoj de naciaj Esperanto asocioj estas aŭtomate anoj de la UEA**, aŭ ĉu oni devas aparte aniĝi ĉe la UEA?

---

I recently joined the Esperanto Association of my country of birth, the *Esperanto Asocio de Britio*.

Meanwhile I was looking at the information for the 102nd *Universala Kongreso*, and I noticed that there were discounts for members of the *Universala Esperanto Asocio*.

Presumably the national Esperanto associations are somehow linked to the UEA, but **does being an individual member of a national association automatically make you a member of the UEA as well**, or do you need to join the UEA separately?

Answer (score 4):

Members of the EAB don't have automatic individual membership of the UEA though members of the EAB are associated members. There is a service which allows you to pay your UEA membership fee by sending a cheque to the EAB, I guess this was useful in the past.

See

http://esperanto.org.uk/eab/member.htm

---

EAB-anoj ne estas aŭtomate membroj de la UEA, kvankam EAB-anoj estas asociitaj membroj de la UEA. Ekzistas servo per kiu oni povas pagi la membriĝo kotizon per ĉeko al la EAB. Mi supozas, ke tio estis utile estintece.

Vidu (angle):

http://esperanto.org.uk/eab/member.htm

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I think it mostly answers my question, but probably the best answer would give general information about national membership, rather than just specific information about one country, even if it is the specific country I mentioned in my question. Maybe you could edit your answer to make it more general, and include your example as such? :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have general information, I just happened to know about the EAB since I am also a member. Thanks for translating my reply!

Comment: As I explain in my answer, UEA has two different kinds of members, so this answer is not really correct.

Comment: I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @harlandski I have updated my answer, it would be cool if you updated your translation.

Comment: @conor I've done that now, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 3):

In Germany, members of the *German Esperanto Association* (GEA) are counted as "corporate" members within UEA. UEA does only offer directly its services to individual members. The number of corporate members is only important for balancing the importance of different countries in elections for the "komitato".

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I think it partially answers my question, but probably the best answer would give general information about national membership, rather than just specific information about one country. Maybe you could edit your answer to make it more general, and include your example as such? :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Ne, esti nacia asociano kaj esti membro de la UEA estas malsamaj aferoj.** Fakte la UEA prezentas [informojn pri ĉiuj landoj kun Esperanto-asocioj](http://www.uea.org/landoj/tutmonde), kaj oni povas facile vidi, ke la kvanto de naciaj asocianoj estas kutime multe pli granda ol la nombro de UEA-membroj el la sama lando. Ekzemple la Esperanto Asocio de [Argentino](http://www.uea.org/landoj/argentino) havas 140 anojn, kvankam tie loĝas nur 29 membroj de la UEA. Simile, [Venezuelo](http://www.uea.org/landoj/venezuelo) havas 32 naciajn asocianojn, kaj 7 UEA-anojn.

---

**No, being a member of a national Esperanto asociation and being a UEA member are different things.** In fact the UEA gives [information about all countries with Esperanto associations](http://www.uea.org/landoj/tutmonde), and it is easy to ascertain that the number of members of national associations is usually much greater than the number of UEA members from the same country. For example, the Esperanto Asociation of [Argentina](http://www.uea.org/landoj/argentino) has 140 members, whereas only 29 members of the UEA reside there. Similarly [Venezuela](http://www.uea.org/landoj/venezuelo) has 32 national association members, and 7 UEA members.

Answer (score 3):

UEA havas du specojn de membroj, individuajn membrojn kaj aligitajn membrojn. Kiel membro de landa asocio de UEA (kiel EAB) vi aŭtomate estas aligita membro de UEA. Sed por ricevi rabaton ĉe aliĝo al UK (aŭ aliajn avantaĝojn por membroj), vi devas esti individua membro de UEA.

---

UEA has two kinds of members, *individuaj membroj* (individual members) and *aligitaj membroj* (associated member). By being a member of a national organization associated to UEA (e.g. EAB), you are automatically an associated member of UEA. But for getting a discount for the *Universala Kongreso* (or other advantages for members), you have to be an individual member of UEA.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**, you are a member of UEA if you are a member of a member organization.

**NO**, you don't get basically any benefit from UEA unless you register as an individual member directly at UEA, because they only see members of associate organisations for the member count, they don't actually have a member administration of the member organisations.